# Shadow Overlapping Polygon

Tags: javascript, canvas, shadow

I am trying to add a drop shadow behind my trihex, but the shadow overlaps the actual image when it should be behind it. I've tried fixing this, but either adding a temporary canvas or somehow bringing the trihex forward just does work. 
Here's the jsfiddle link so you can see what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/r0dkeu1g/3/

Here is where the shadow is being created:

```
function drawHexagon(canvasContext, x, y, fill) {
    fill++;           
    var fill = fill || false;

    canvasContext.shadowColor = "rgb(45, 44, 44)"; //Here is the shadow
    canvasContext.shadowBlur = 5;
    canvasContext.shadowOffsetX = 5;
    canvasContext.shadowOffsetY = 5; //Shadow Ends

    canvasContext.beginPath(); //Start drawing hexagaon
    canvasContext.moveTo(x + hexRadius, y);
    canvasContext.lineTo(x + hexRectangleWidth, y + hexHeight);
    canvasContext.lineTo(x + hexRectangleWidth, y + hexHeight + sideLength);
    canvasContext.lineTo(x + hexRadius, y + hexRectangleHeight);
    canvasContext.lineTo(x, y + sideLength + hexHeight);
    canvasContext.lineTo(x, y + hexHeight);
    canvasContext.closePath(); // Stop drawing hexagon
    //Unrelated, this is just where some colors are set
    if(fill) {
        switch(fill){
            case 1:
                canvasContext.fillStyle = JUNGLECOLOR;
                break;
            case 2:                 
                canvasContext.fillStyle = GRASSCOLOR;
                break;
            case 3:
                canvasContext.fillStyle = DESERTCOLOR;
                break;
            case 4:
                canvasContext.fillStyle = QUARRYCOLOR;
                break;
            case 5:
                canvasContext.fillStyle = LAGOONCOLOR;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
        canvasContext.fillStyle = VOLCANOCOLOR;
    }
        canvasContext.fill();
        canvasContext.strokeStyle = "white";
        canvasContext.stroke();
}
```

Basically, there's a bit of the shadow overlapping the trihex.

Comment: The stroke also creates a shadow. So you have two shadows. one for the fill and the other drawn on top is the shadow of the stroke..You need to turn of the shadow before you draw the stroke or you will need some more complicated code to have the shadows correct.

Comment: When you say turn off the shadow before the stroke, what does this mean? Should I move the shadows outside of the function?

Comment: I took out the stroke from within the function and changed it to just call afterwards, but then for some reason only the left hexagon gets the white stroke style and it seems like its above the rest of the image.

Comment: I just had a look at your fiddle and its will take some more complex work to get shadows as you are also getting a shadow from one hex over the others. You need to draw the hexs in two passes. First draw all the hexs with the shadows turned on. This will create the base shadows. but with over lap. Then redraw all the hexs once more but without the shadow. Or draw the hexs to an offscreen canvas an then just draw that canvas with the shadow on to the display canvas.

Comment: I just tried to implement the redraw and it did not produce the results, the shadows still seem to appear. Perhaps I did it wrong? If it's not too much trouble could you demonstrate with that jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Shadows via layering.

The shadows on 2D canvas are not mean for anything but the simplest of rendering. They are slow and if you have more than one color you end up with all sorts of layering and composition problems.

The quickest solution for your problem is to render in two passes (or layers). First layer or so called shadow pass is when you draw with the shadows turned on.

Then when all the shadows are drawn you then do the next layer rendering the top layer so that no shadows overlap the layer above.

### Quick example of two pass shadows.

```js
// the colours from your fiddle

const JUNGLECOLOR  = 'rgba(0, 100, 0, 255)'; 
const GRASSCOLOR   = 'rgba(0, 225, 0, 255)'; 
const DESERTCOLOR  = 'rgba(255, 201, 102, 255)';
const QUARRYCOLOR  = 'rgba(123, 123, 139, 255)';
const LAGOONCOLOR  = 'rgba(0, 191, 255, 255)';
const VOLCANOCOLOR = 'rgba(255, 48, 48, 255)';
var colors = [JUNGLECOLOR, GRASSCOLOR , DESERTCOLOR, QUARRYCOLOR, LAGOONCOLOR, VOLCANOCOLOR ];

// Get context and set settings
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const hexSize = 40;
const hexGridCenterX = 150;
const hexGridCenterY = 100;
ctx.lineWidth = 2;


// function only creates a hex path does not draw
function drawHex(x,y,size){
  ctx.moveTo(x ,       y - size);
  ctx.lineTo(x + size, y - size/2);
  ctx.lineTo(x + size, y + size/2);
  ctx.lineTo(x ,       y + size);  
  ctx.lineTo(x - size, y + size/2);
  ctx.lineTo(x - size, y - size/2);
  ctx.closePath();
}

// Draw a hex with colour and outline. Calls the function above.
function drawHexColor(x, y, size, col){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = col;

  ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
  drawHex(x,y,size);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke()
}

// Draws all hexs at once so that the shadows are not
// overlapping each other, which is just as bad as over lapping stuff
// above.
function shadowPass(){
   const x = hexGridCenterX;
   const y = hexGridCenterY;
   ctx.save(); // save state 
   ctx.shadowColor = "rgb(45, 44, 44)";
   ctx.shadowBlur = 5;
   ctx.shadowOffsetX = 5;
   ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
   ctx.fillStyle = "black";
   ctx.beginPath(); // the colour does not mater at the moment
   drawHex(x - hexSize, y + hexSize, hexSize);
   drawHex(x + hexSize, y + hexSize, hexSize);
   drawHex(x          , y - hexSize + hexSize / 2, hexSize);
   ctx.fill(); // creates the shadows;
   ctx.restore(); // restore the state which turns off shadows
}

// Draws just the hexs with color and no shadow
function colorPass(){
   const x = hexGridCenterX;
   const y = hexGridCenterY;

   drawHexColor(x - hexSize, y + hexSize, hexSize, colors[2]);
   drawHexColor(x + hexSize, y + hexSize, hexSize, colors[1]);
   drawHexColor(x          , y - hexSize + hexSize / 2, hexSize, colors[5]);

}


// Draw shadows first
shadowPass(); // that puts the shadow under everything
// Then draw the colours without shadows ontop
colorPass();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

### Using sprites is another option.

Personally this type of display is best suited to pre rendered content. Draw the hexs and shadows as bitmap sprites and then layer them. But that is a lot of work.